# TypeError: sheet3.getRange(...).setVaules is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am trying to automate a filter by dates from a range of data. However, I am not getting a permissive. I am getting a "TypeError: sheet3.getRange(...).setVaules is not a function" once I try to run the program.

Does anyone have any guidance on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

right name is `setValues()`, not `setVaules()`

Comment: Please don't [answer questions that are only caused by a typo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo). Instead, please flag the question as such and point it out in the comments.